# MongoDb: In a many to many relation, when does it make sense to make the ids of both models in the definition of the other model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have this relation:

> User has many courses

I have implemented it by integrating the user_id in the definition of the Course model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    //This will associate the user by his id
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  }, 
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Course = mongoose.model("course", CourseSchema);
```

This way, if I want to get the courses created by a user X, I just use his id and look it up in the courses documents.

I thought with a big data base, this operation may be costly.
So I should add the course_id, to an array property called courses in the User model:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  courses: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "course",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

This way, I can simply populate that array with the `.populate` operation, instead of going with the appraoach mentioned above.

I would like to know if my way of thinking makes sense.
And whether there other reasons for me to add the course_id, to courses property in the User model.

Answer (score 0):

both approach is correctly I have seen both methods that uses

but when you want to using populate, you should update two collections(users and courses) when you want to insert a new `Course`, so you should use [transaction](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) because if one was updated and the other did not(An error occurred) rollback be done

the first thing to understand about mongoose population is that it is not magic, but just a convenience method that allows you to retrieve related information without doing it all yourself

if `user id` be `index` in `couresSchema` you can `find()` all courses very fast,
but the generally recommendation is to consider the data usage patterns of your application and choose what is best

Comment: If the database is large, which approach is better?

Comment: For the large database with relation I use postgresql becuase mongodb not desigin for relation, I perfer populete just for clean code, but I think the first method  has better performance